# MISRA C Directive 4.6

Tags: c, misra

> Typedefs that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic numerical types.

Please, can you help me? 
Why does my tool detect a violation for this code:

```
typedef int int_t;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: From the looks of it, `int_t` does not indicate size any more than `int` does.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwidth of `int` depends on the hardware architecture (and sometimes on other parameters like the selection and configuration of the toolchain).
The type only has a minimum bitwidth/value range, but is not required to have certain exact properties.

In contrast, the types `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` and their corresponding unsigned counterparts (same type names but with a `u` prefix) are defined in
[stdint.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)
to provide an exact bitwidth/value range - but leave the question open how efficient they can be used when ported to a different platform.

In Embedded systems (especially those with requirements of safety, security and/or availability), the main concern is that for a given variable type, every platform supports the bitwidth the programmer expected (or conversely, every programmer recognizes the limits of the type used).
Therefore, a good recommendation is to start with the fixed-width types, and only use other types if
[optimization is really necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)
and the risks induced by using non-fixed-width types can be prevented by other measures (which at that time legitimate a MISRA rule deviation).

Answer (score 1):

MISRA-C:2012 supports both C90 and later standards. In modern C we should simply use `stdint.h` and no `typedef`, so that's what I would strongly recommend. Cooking up your own custom types is bad practice.

If you are stuck with C90, then you need to make *identical typedefs as the ones present in `stdint.h`*. Something like this:

```
#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || (__STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L)
  typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
  /* and so on... */
#else
  #include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

C90 did not define `__STDC_VERSION__` and C94 has it as `199409L`, so the above macro covers everything pre-C99.

The above needs to be placed in some project-wide universal header.

Do the same thing with `bool`, `false` and `true` since you don't have `stdbool.h` in C90 either.

Comment: Please note that this isn't just something that you need to do for MISRA-C compliance, all semi-professional projects must do this, embedded ones in particular.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the limitation about C versions (and how to work around them) - I had forgotten that those types are among the "goodies" of C99...